# How can i get dynamic element from website so I can use it on a nightwatch

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I want to get "Cancel" element. But the element of Cancel Button is dynamic, like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka6JR.png)

```
//*[@id="TD/D0202/22/00321-content"]/div/button[1]/span
```

How can i use the element to my nightwatch script?

Answer (score 0):

CSS Selector:

```
span[class = "MuiButton-label"]
button[class*= "MuiButtonBase"] span[class = "MuiButton-label"]
```

XPATH Selector:

```
//span[@class = "MuiButton-label"]
//span[@class = "MuiButton-label" and contains(text(), "Cancel")]
//button[contains(@class, "MuiButtonBase")]/span
```

There are a lot of possibilities to capture this element.